# padding-top not working but padding-right is

Tags: css

this is my css:

```
body { 
margin: 0px;
background-color: white;
}

#navbar { 
background-color: red;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 900px;
height: 200px;
}

#navbar a { 
padding: 20px;
color: grey;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

navbar is a div inside body and i have a couple of   tags inside navbar.

this is the output:
[image]

Comment: You have set all of the paddings to 20px!!

Comment: change width:900px to width: ...% . You may ge output..

Answer (score 5):

there is a difference between the '**Block level**' elements and '**Inline Elements**'. The Margins & Paddings of 'Inline Elements' effect only in *Horizontal Direction*, but not in *Vertical Direction*, as per the basic concept.

Your Div was a block level element, but **anchor tag** is an inline element. To give vertical space make it a block element, as you've already found out OR put the anchor in a div, which has vertical space in form of 'padding' or 'margin'!

```
div a {display:block;padding:20px;} OR div a{display:inline-block;padding:20px;}
```

In later two cases, padding will now effect in vertical direction also, as  has now converted to block-level element, from inline form. Hope, that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, I just needed to use:  `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eav8wxet/2/)**

```
#navbar a {       
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```